# Ларавель не отправляет почту через mail драйвер

Tags: php, laravel, email

Есть форма. Письма идут на мой ящик example@gmail.com
Если в отправителях указываю почту на mail.ru/yandex.ru то почта не приходит, а если указать что то другое например user@over.rucom тогда почта приходит.
А если отправляю на мейл и указываю ящик gmail то приходит письмо, но с пометкой что не могут проверить подлинность отправителя.

С этим можно что то сделать? и почему так происходит

Comment: Все верно, ты указываешь отправителя, не совпадающего доменным именем  сервера с которого идет отправка письма, так как бы не "надежный". Спам фильтр  принимает тебя за спам (считай что тебя взломали и отсылают от тебя почту) доверия к тебе нет, отправляй через smtp, или настрой сервер так что б адрес отправителя и совпадал с доменным именем

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Gmail, mail, yandex и другие используют проверки отправителя DKIM, SPF, DMARC. Чтобы отправлять почту именно со стороннего почтового сервиса нужно использовать smtp.

Можно отправлять с локального сервера, и указывать обратный адрес - нужный адрес, но существует большая вероятность попасть в спам, если локальный сервер не настроен должным образом.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой.Gmail, mail.ru не принимали почту. Решением проблемы было использование mailable laravel. Посмотрите здесь https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-and-fast-emails-with-laravel-5-3-mailables