# Почему не отправляется заявка формы на почту?

Tags: php, html

Я в php почти ноль, и мне нужно срочно 
настроить отправку формы на почту. 
Прошу, скажите что не так в коде?

```
if(!isset($_POST['name']) and !isset($_POST['email']) and !isset($_POST['tel']) and !isset($_POST['adress'])){
 ?> <form class="form" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" class="form__input">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Почта" class="form__input">
    <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Телефон" class="form__input">
    <input type="text" name="adress" placeholder="Адрес" class="form__input">
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ" class="form__input form__btn">
</form> <?php
} else {
//показываем форму
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];

$name = htmlspecialchars($name);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);
$tel = htmlspecialchars($tel);
$adress = htmlspecialchars($adress);

$name = trim($name);
$email = trim($email);
$tel = trim($tel);
$adress = trim($adress);

mail("ilyanimation@mail.ru", "Заявка с сайта", "Имя:".$name.". Почта: ".$email.". Телефон: ".$tel.". Адрес: ".$adress ,"From: vishnyak_ilya@mail.ru \r\n");

if (mail("ilyanimation@mail.ru", "Заявка с сайта", "Имя:".$name.". Почта: ".$email.". Телефон: ".$tel.". Адрес: ".$adress ,"From: vishnyak_ilya@mail.ru \r\n"))
 {
    echo "сообщение успешно отправлено";
} else {
    echo "при отправке сообщения возникли ошибки";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Какая конкретно проблема возникает? Ошибка? Или письмо не доходит?

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот вопрос и ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/872882/263405

Comment: Вообще использовать метод `mail` является небезопасным и крайне редко рабочим. Советую переходить на SMTP. Проверьте логи отправки сообщения и возможности отправки почты с сервера.

Comment: в php теперь можно использовать `and`?)

Comment: @tCode можно, но не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

В части вызова функции `mail()` в коде ошибки нет. Но есть ошибка выше по стеку, то есть на уровне почтовых серверов.

Обычно это может быть как проблема настройки сервера откуда идёт отправка, так и проблема на стороне сервера получателя писем - как в этом случае.

Сервер получателя может отказаться принимать письма из-за поддельного адреса отправителя, и правильно сделает. Попробуйте без него - для этого достаточно убрать последний аргумент в вызове функции.

Answer (score 0):

Почтовиками проверяется соответствие - что указано в поле FROM и откуда было отправлено письмо на самом деле. Почтовый сервер получателя видит, что письмо отправлено якобы от mail.ru, но письмо на самом деле с отправлено с серверов хостера (или с машины разработчика) и делает вывод, что письмо является спамом и его нужно пометить как “спам” (или удалить, в особо тяжёлых случаях). В случае большого потока подобных писем, почтовый сервер может забанить отправителя по IP временно (greylist) или навечно (blacklist)

Особой “жестокостью” отличился mail.ru и, в последнее время, Rambler. Эти товарищи очень бодро банят сервера при малейшем намёке на спам. Если у вас есть возможность не использовать для сайта почтовый ящик на mail.ru - не используйте.

И обязательно ставьте письмам правильный заголовок. Письмо отправляется с ford.ru? Пишем в заголовок admin@ford.ru. Письмо отправляется с example.com? Пишем в заголовок admin@example.com. И так далее.

Если письмо отправляется с локальной машины и никакого сайта еще нет - отправляйте через SMTP. Можете взять для этого библиотеку - например, PHPMailer